# Mysql: How to query a column whose type is bit?

Tags: mysql, select, bit

Hi I am using hibernate and Mysql. I have a class with a boolean attribute called 'active'.

The generated database table has the BIT data type. So far so good.
I want to query this value but I don't know how to do it.
I've tried

```
 SELECT * from table where active = 1
```

doesn't work, neither the following

```
 SELECT * from table where active = true
```

I didn't find anything neither in the reference manual nor at Stackoveflow.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE active = (1)
```

Answer (score 24):

According to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html), BIT is a synonym for TINYINT(1) for versions **before 5.0.3**.

Have you tried these?

```
SELECT * from table where active = (1)
SELECT * from table where active = 'true'
SELECT * from table where active = b'1'
```

This [blog entry](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/) suggests to avoid the BIT data type altogether.

Comment: The first and the third entry are coorect whereas the second doesn't work, at least under my Mysql installation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Andomar Disagree to avoid BIT data type. The disadvantage is interoperability with older versions, assuming you don't need it, BIT actually stores data more compactly and hence save storage space.

Comment: @Pacerier I don't see how BIT saves storage space. TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED 1 byte and BIT(1) 1 byte.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html (same with 5.7)

Answer (score 7):

To specify bit values, b'value' notation can be used.

Comment: @Alvaro: This question is almost 4 years old!

Answer (score 7):

Actually MySQL has built-in bit literals:

```
select*from table where active = 0b1
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried casting it to an Integer for comparison

```
SELECT * from table where cast(active as unsigned) = 1
```

I use MS SQL most of the time so forgive me if this does not work as I cannot test it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for both comparisons and updates, 0 and 1 work for me:

Here's a field of type bit(1), one row, the field is currently false:

```
mysql> select isfeatured from nodes where isfeatured = 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select isfeatured from nodes where isfeatured = 0;
+------------+
| isfeatured |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Update changing 0 to 1 in isfeatured, which is type bit(1)...

```
mysql> update nodes set isfeatured=1 where isfeatured = 0;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

One row changed... Try it again:

```
mysql> update nodes set isfeatured=1 where isfeatured = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

No rows changed as expected.

Same select queries as before:

```
mysql> select isfeatured from nodes where isfeatured = 1;
+------------+
| isfeatured |
+------------+
|           |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select isfeatured from nodes where isfeatured = 0;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

See, it works.

I'm using:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

and

/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 5.5.31-0+wheezy1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Debian))