# MySQL PDO Error: 'Data too long for column' when passing a boolean parameter for a BIT column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The only similar question I have found is: [Insert php boolean into mysql bit column with Zend_Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752915/insert-php-boolean-into-mysql-bit-column-with-zend-db) but this has no answer.

Please see below a simplified test:

The 'allow' column type is BIT.
The 'roleID' column type is INT.
The 'permID' column type is INT.

```
$dbo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=127.0.0.1", "phpuser", "pass");

$query = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO ws_role_perms (allow, roleID, permID)
                            VALUES (:allow, :roleID, :permID)");

$query->bindValue("allow", true, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$query->bindValue("roleID", 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue("permID", 2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($query->execute() == false) {
    throw new Exception(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
}
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Array (
    [0] => 22001
    [1] => 1406
    [2] => Data too long for column 'allow' at row 1
)
```

If I attempt to put the equivalent query straight into MySQL, i.e. by running the query: `INSERT INTO ws_role_perms (allow, roleID, permID) VALUES (true, 1, 2)`
I have no problems.

Is this a bug in the MySQL PDO driver, or is it just me?

Many thanks in anticipation of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though PHP is not interpreting 'true' as a boolean. [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) indicates that PDO::PARAM_BOOL is an integer. The MySQL interpretation of a column with  [datatype 'bit'](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/) changed after around version 5.0. What this means is that PHP is probably trying to insert a full integer (32 bits) into a column that has an unpredictable number of bits (1-64).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

I have tried with:
`$query->bindValue("allow", 1, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);`

However, this still fails.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And in particular, do you know your character set?

Comment: Results of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`  

innodb_version 1.1.8  
protocol_version 10  
slave_type_conversions 
version 5.5.22  
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)  
version_compile_machine x86  
version_compile_os Win64  

I am using the 'UTF8 - default collection' Character set.

Comment: I've updated the solution; it seems that the mysql interpretation of 'bit' is a bit fuzzy. Can you alter the table to have it be something other than 'bit' and rather something like tinyint(1)?

Comment: I have changed the data type to tinyint(1) and this works fine. I have recently migrated from MS SQL Server, and had assumed that the BIT type was the same as MS SQL.  
Many thanks

Comment: I run the same code base on two different server. The one on Azure, I have less control of. The instance running on XAMPP takes `bit(1)` as `bool` but the other chokes as `Data too long for column...`. `tinyint(1)` is the other officially accepted `bool` type for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Cast function:

```
Values ( CAST( :allow AS UNSIGNED), :roleID, :permID)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = $dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE roles SET isTrue= b? WHERE itemID = ?;");
$result = $query->execute(array(true, $productID_GET));
```

Use 'b' before the variable to convert any value to a bit.

In my case, I also have a bit column and I was getting the same error. That's how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I have `ANSI` and `TRADITIONAL` mode enabled and I had to use the following construct:

```
IFNULL(IF(?,TRUE,FALSE),NULL)
```

In case you provide a PHP 'null' it will set the column to NULL. Else MySQL will evaluate the provided variable. If it is zero the column will be set to FALSE, if it is non-zero the column will be set to TRUE.

I hope this helps.