# MySQL select bit(1) shows as string(3)

Tags: php, mysql, bit

I have a table with a column `bit(1)` and the following query: `SELECT my_bit FROM my_table`.

When I `echo` the result on a `php` page the value shows up as `string(3)` `%qu` **whether the bit value on a column is 0 or 1**. How is this possible?

The following query resolved the issue when `echoing` on a web page: `SELECT CAST(my_bit AS UNSIGNED) AS my_bit FROM my_table`.

However, both of the queries above work on a command line tool. No `string(3)`s there.

Also everything works when selecting data, no difference between

1. SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_bit=0
2. SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_bit=(0)

when using command line tool or web interface `php` pages. (The latter is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839596/mysql-how-to-query-a-column-whose-type-is-bit).) `Echoing` has to be done using `CAST` function but the `WHERE` is not affected by the parentehis: correct rows are returned.

### Main questions

1. How come the returned `bit` type value is `echoed` as identical `string` whether the `bit` value is 0 or 1?
2. Are there any special issues that should be taken into consideration when inserting/selecting data using `bit(1)` type column? (Quick testing shows that everything works as intended: 0 get inserted as 0 and 1 as 1, but I might be missing something.)

I'm testing this locally with MAMP: PHP 5.3.2 and MySQL 5.1.44. Command line tool refers to Sequel Pro (not MAMP's PhpAdmin). `Php` pages are `utf-8` and queries use `SET NAMES 'utf8'`.

---

### Update: code

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `my_bit` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`lto_muu`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `my_bit`) VALUES (null, 0), (null,1)

//php page
//query option 1
SELECT `id`, `my_bit`  FROM `my_table`
//query option 2
SELECT `id`, CAST(`my_bit` AS UNSIGNED) AS `my_bit`  FROM `my_table`

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root","my_db");
$q = "SELECT `id`, `my_bit`  FROM `my_table`";//returns 2 rows

$r = $mysqli->query($q);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo 'id: ' . $row['id'] . ' - bit: ' . $row['my_bit'] . '<br />';
}
```

Query option 1 prints out:

```
id: 1 - bit: %qu
id: 2 - bit: %qu
```

Query option 2 prints out:

```
id: 1 - bit: 0
id: 2 - bit: 1
```

---

### Update 2: Álvaro's code

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root','test');
//$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$conn->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bit_test');
$conn->query('CREATE TABLE bit_test (
    my_bit BIT(1) NULL,
    my_multiple_bit BIT(8) NULL
)');
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'0', b'111')");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'1', b'10000000')");

//opt 1
$q = 'SELECT cast(my_bit as unsigned) as my_bit, my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';
//opt2 
//$q = 'SELECT my_bit, my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';
$r = $conn->query($q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo bin2hex($row['my_bit']) . '<br />';
    echo bin2hex($row['my_multiple_bit']) . '<br />';
    var_dump($row);
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Using **PHP 5.2.12** opt 1 and 2 both print:

```
30
07
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(1) ""
}
31
80
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(1) "�"
}
```

Using **PHP 5.3.2** opt 1 prints:

```
30
257175
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(3) "%qu"
}
31
257175
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(3) "%qu"
}
```

And opt 2:

```
257175
257175
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(3) "%qu"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(3) "%qu"
}
257175
257175
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(3) "%qu"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(3) "%qu"
}
```

PHP 5.3.2 alvays prints `%qu`. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I always get either the raw binary bits or the decimal representation of the binary number, depending on how I test. I don't think this question can be solved without seeing your code.

Comment: I'm afraid I still cannot reproduce it. I get `id: 1 - bit: 0<br />id: 2 - bit: 1<br />` with both queries.

Comment: @alvaro I have MAMP with PHP 5.3.2. I tried the other alternative available in MAMP: PHP 5.2.13. That prints out nothing with query option 2 althought `var_dump()` shows `["my_bit"]=> string(1) ""`. Why is empty string 1 in length. The issue seems to solely related to PHP version. Or are there other explanations?

Comment: `string(1)` means there's one byte. It doesn't need to be a printable char. If you don't have an hexadecimal editor you can use [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex) to inspect it.

Comment: Is your code using bind variables?

Comment: @alvaro I looked your edit and used your code with minute changes, see above. I don't get any additional rows with NULL values, just 2 rows which are on the table. Our PHP versions cross. Could this be the (only) explanation? Thank you for your suggestions and input so far.

Comment: The `0x07` and `0x80` output you get with PHP/5.2.12 are the correct numbers (`7` and `128` in decimal) except that you get a raw binary string instead of a number. Those `%qu` in PHP/5.3.2 must be a PHP bug (it looks like some kind of C printf sequence). As last resort, I suggest you either try PHP/5.4 or `CAST(`my_bit` AS UNSIGNED)` every time.

Comment: @alvaro I guess I have to use `CAST` every time to be sure. Production server has PHP 5.2.6 and I haven't tested that one yet – nor can I change the PHP version of it. Hopefully this is a PHP 5.3.2 bug which **can always be avoided** using `CAST`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a full example on how to retrieve `BIT` column types:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=test;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$conn->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bit_test');
$conn->query('CREATE TABLE bit_test (
    my_bit BIT(1) NULL,
    my_multiple_bit BIT(8) NULL
)');
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'0', b'111')");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'1', b'10000000')");

$res = $conn->query('SELECT my_bit, my_multiple_bit FROM test');
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

... which prints:

```
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
array(2) {
  ["my_bit"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["my_multiple_bit"]=>
  string(3) "128"
}
```

**Edit #1:**

Here's my previous code, adapted to mysqli:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test','test');

$conn->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bit_test');
$conn->query('CREATE TABLE bit_test (
    my_bit BIT(1) NULL,
    my_multiple_bit BIT(8) NULL
)');
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'0', b'111')");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'1', b'10000000')");

$res = $conn->query('SELECT my_bit, my_multiple_bit FROM test');
#while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

I get an additional array item with all values set to `NULL` (I'm not familiar with mysqli so it's probably my fault) but output is otherwise identical. I've tested it in PHP/5.3.0 and PHP/5.4.5.

I suggest you try my code verbatim and verify whether you still get `%qu` or something weird. I have a strong feeling that such `%qu` string might be leaking from somewhere else...

**Edit #2:**

From the additional information, I think we can conclude the following:

- Earlier PHP versions retrieved `BIT` columns as-is, as raw binary strings (`0x07` and `0x80` are the correct numbers, `7` and `128` in decimal).
- At some point, automatic encoding was added and `BIT` columns started being retrieved as decimals.
- The PHP release used by the OP probably has a bug in the encoding code: `%qu` reminds of me C printf modifiers (though I couldn't find its exact definition).

Given the different behaviours, a workaround is required to ensure coherent output:

- `CAST(my_bit AS UNSIGNED)` to generate a decimal number
- `HEX(my_bit)` to generate an hexadecimal number

Comment: Added code, sorry it took a while. I use an `ajax` call on my page and singleton class to connect to the DB but the example code recreates the issue. Please let me know if any additional information is necessary and if you are not able to recreate the issue with the example code.

Comment: +1 yesterday for your help. I dug a little deeper and added an answer of my own. If no one offers better explanation or prove either of us wrong I'll accept your anwer or mine in a few days. Your hexadecimal/decimal views helped a lot. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Accepted this answer since it helped me to understand the original issue. This answer has also a working solution. Be sure to check my answer also for additional working solution.

Answer (score 8):

## Short answer

OK, here's are short and long answers to my own question. If you want to be sure that `bit(1)` column gets retrieved as an integer use the following query when retrieving `bit(1)` values:

`$q = 'SELECT (my_bit + 0) AS my_bit, (my_multiple_bit + 0) AS my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';`

If "+ 0" is not used the value of a `bit(1)` column is treated as `binary string`.
[This is the moment when I say "RTM" to myself...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-value-literals.html)

[Something similar is found here through the magic of Google...](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/157028/#758144)

**If you are happy with quick solution, stop reading now.**

## Now the messy/long answer (let's use Álvaro's code)

Let's create the table and use four different queries with two PHP versions available on my MAMP installation: 5.3.2 & 5.2.12.

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root','my_db');

$conn->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bit_test');
$conn->query('CREATE TABLE bit_test (
    my_bit BIT(1) NULL,
    my_multiple_bit BIT(8) NULL
)');

$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'0', b'111')");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO bit_test (my_bit, my_multiple_bit) VALUES (b'1', b'10000000')");

//q1
$q = 'SELECT (my_bit + 0) AS my_bit, (my_multiple_bit + 0) AS my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';
//q2
//$q = 'SELECT cast(my_bit as unsigned) as my_bit, my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';
//q3
//$q = 'SELECT HEX(my_bit) AS my_bit , HEX(my_multiple_bit) AS my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';
//q4
//$q = 'SELECT my_bit, my_multiple_bit FROM bit_test';

$r = $conn->query($q);

//let's echo a few options
//plain gives unaltered result
//bin2hex gives hexadecimal number of an ASCII string (since) the values are treated as strings
//base16to10 gives decimal representation of hexadecimal value
//yes, the two functions are contradictionary (dependable of the query in use)
//but I'll echo their result anyway
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  echo 'plain: ' . $row['my_bit'] . '<br />';
  echo 'plain: ' . $row['my_multiple_bit'] . '<br />';
  echo 'bin2hex: ' . bin2hex($row['my_bit']) . '<br />';
  echo 'bin2hex: ' . bin2hex($row['my_multiple_bit']) . '<br />';
  echo 'base16to10: ' . base_convert($row['my_bit'],16,10) . '<br />';
  echo 'base16to10: ' . base_convert($row['my_multiple_bit'],16,10) . '<br />';
  var_dump($row);
  echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

### Here are the results of different queries

What I'm really interested in is the plain output and `var_dump`, but you can also check the `bin2hex` and `base16to10` output can be useful when looking up if the numbers have some link to their corresponding values: numbers 0, 7, 1 and 128 (the values stored into four `bit`columns of the table).

#### q1 – the safe bet – output is identical in PHP 5.3.2 & 5.2.12

```
plain: 0
plain: 7
bin2hex: 30
bin2hex: 37
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 7
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "0" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(1) "7" }

plain: 1
plain: 128
bin2hex: 31
bin2hex: 313238
base16to10: 1
base16to10: 296
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "1" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(3) "128" }
```

#### q2 – some differences in output

Works fine with `bit(1)` but something is quite wrong in `my_multiple_bit` output.

PHP 5.2.12:

```
plain: 0
plain: 
bin2hex: 30
bin2hex: 07
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "0" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(1) "" }

plain: 1
plain: �
bin2hex: 31
bin2hex: 80
base16to10: 1
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "1" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(1) "�" }
```

PHP 5.3.2

```
plain: 0
plain: %qu
bin2hex: 30
bin2hex: 257175
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "0" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(3) "%qu" }

plain: 1
plain: %qu
bin2hex: 31
bin2hex: 257175
base16to10: 1
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "1" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(3) "%qu" }
```

#### q3 – output is identical in PHP 5.3.2 & 5.2.12

This is also a safe query to use. Just remember to convert retrieved hexadecimal to decimal number.

```
plain: 0
plain: 7
bin2hex: 30
bin2hex: 37
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 7
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "0" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(1) "7" }

plain: 1
plain: 80
bin2hex: 31
bin2hex: 3830
base16to10: 1
base16to10: 128
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "1" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(2) "80" }
```

#### q4 – output is quite strange

PHP 5.2.12 works fine with `bit(1)` but I wouldn't use this query if there's any doubt about PHP version in use or it's behaviour.

PHP 5.2.12

```
plain:
plain: 
bin2hex: 00
bin2hex: 07
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(1) "" }

plain: 
plain: �
bin2hex: 01
bin2hex: 80
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(1) "" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(1) "�" }
```

PHP 5.3.2

```
plain: %qu
plain: %qu
bin2hex: 257175
bin2hex: 257175
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(3) "%qu" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(3) "%qu" }

plain: %qu
plain: %qu
bin2hex: 257175
bin2hex: 257175
base16to10: 0
base16to10: 0
array(2) { ["my_bit"]=> string(3) "%qu" ["my_multiple_bit"]=> string(3) "%qu" }
```

### Final thoughts and note to self

RTM, test and test again.

Also it would be nice to know for sure if this `%qu` output is an exclusive PHP 5.3.2 bug. (Or what other PHP versions are affected.)

So, Álvaro's answer is correct in sense that use `CAST` or retrieve `HEX` values from DB. [The manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-value-literals.html) revealed additional "+0" method which seems take the pain away from different PHP versions behaviour. Hence the short answer is way on the top...