# BIT data type with radio buttons (selected/unselected)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok searched here and many many sites on Google results for this but can't find an exact fix for my issue.

I have a sql pulling a name and an office. So it goes something like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT myStaff_tbl.firstName, myStaff_tbl.lastName, myOffice_tbl.officeName,
    myOfficeLoc_tbl.primary_loc_bit 
    FROM myOfficeLoc_tbl 
    INNER JOIN myOffice_tbl ON myOfficeLoc_tbl.office_Id = myOffice_tbl.office_Id
    INNER JOIN myStaff_tbl ON myOfficeLoc_tbl.staff_Id = myStaff_tbl.staff_Id
    WHERE location_tbl.staffID = $myvariable"
```

And my html looks like this:

```
    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="bit_primary_loc" value="" <?php if ($row_rs_myQuery['primary_loc_bit'] == 1) {echo "checked='checked'";} ?> > </td>
```

of course my html is wrapped in a loop statement checking to see if there is more than one office location associated with this staff member. If there are multiple locations it will spit them out. But my problem at the moment is just getting it to output the $row_rs_myQuery['primary_loc_bit'] right now when I try to var_dump the row or just simply echo that it shows blank.

I want the radio button to be checked if that office is set as the staff members primary location and because they can only have 1 primary location it needs to be a radio button.

Any ideas why it wouldn't be showing as checked if it is indeed showing when I run the sql query in my  phpMyAdmin?

Just for reference I get something like this when I run the sql in my phpMyAdmin

```
    Steve Smith   Portland   1
    Steve Smith   Salem      0
    Steve Smith   Ontario    0
```

Comment: If you run that loop in a test file, try to var_dump `$row_rs_myQuery` and see what you get?

Comment: the var_dump gives me this ["primary_loc_bit"]=> string(1) ""

Comment: Interesting. What type does it have in the database table? Boolean?

Comment: Dear lord, the BIT data type is not used for that kind of purposes. You need to change it to BOOL, because `primary_loc_bit` can only be true or false, right?

Comment: ahh I was just going off someone else's suggestion to use that it is only holding a 1 or a 0 I can change it to see if that works. Let me check.

Comment: can I use a tiny int for this instead? I have like 60 some staff members already in the database.

Comment: BOOL is the same as TINYINT(3). It has nothing to do with how many records you have in your table.

Comment: Oh I only asked because I tried to change to BOOL and it now says tiny_int :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get what seems to be an empty string  is because the BIT data type stores a value that equals to the ASCII code of a character. The ASCII code equal to 1 is [`START OF HEADER`](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/start-of-header-ascii-code-1.html), which is an invisible, non-printable character. Use `BOOL` (`TINYINT(3)`) instead when you want a column value that either can be `TRUE` or `FALSE` (on or off).

> See also: [Mysql: How to query a column whose type is bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839614/633098)

Comment: I actually looked at that thread but didn't see how to insert my information into it. however changing it from a bit to a tinyint fixes my problem. I am now checking for true instead of 1 or 0 thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, you just introduced me to the BIT data type as well =P